# Pitfalls of the New AngularJS ng-ref Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

The release of AngularJS V1.7.1<sup>[*](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#171-momentum-defiance-2018-06-08)</sup> introduces the new [ng-ref directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef#overview). While this new directive enables users to easily do certain things, I see great potential for abuse and problems.

The [ng-ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef#overview) attribute tells AngularJS to publish the controller of a component on the current scope. This is useful for having a component such as an audio player expose its API to sibling components. Its play and stop controls can be easily accessed.

The first problem is the player controls are `undefined` inside the `$onInit` function of the controller.

```
Initial vm.pl = undefined  <<<< UNDEFINED
Sample = [true,false]
```

For code that depends on data being available, **how do we fix this?**

### [The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vt8zj589iuNYAjeNLq1E?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", class ctrl {
  constructor() {
    console.log("construct")
  }
  $onInit() {
    console.log("onInit", this.pl);
    this.initPL = this.pl || 'undefined';
    this.sample = this.pl || 'undefined';
    this.getSample = () => {
      this.sample = `[${this.pl.box1},${this.pl.box2}]`;
    }
  }
})
.component("player", {
  template: `
    <fieldset>
      $ctrl.box1={{$ctrl.box1}}<br>
      $ctrl.box2={{$ctrl.box2}}<br>
      <h3>Player</h3>
    </fieldset>
  `,
  controller: class player {
    constructor() {
      console.log("player",this);
    }
    $onInit() {
      console.log("pl.init", this)
      this.box1 = true;
      this.box2 = false;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.7.1/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    Initial vm.pl = {{vm.initPL}}<br>
    Sample = {{vm.sample}}<br>
    <button ng-click="vm.getSample()">Get Sample</button>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.pl.box1" />
      Box1 pl.box1={{vm.pl.box1}}<br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.pl.box2" />
      Box2 pl.box2={{vm.pl.box2}}<br>
    <br>
    <player ng-ref="vm.pl"></player>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting ref to components controller isn't new, directives back in the day allowed it and that wasn't a problem at all, it's necessary to have such feature, `ng-ref` is just a helper for you to do this from the template side (the same way angular 2+ does).

Nevertheless, if you need the child components ready you should use `$postLink()` instead of `$onInit`. `$postLink` is called after the component is linked with his children, which means, the `ng-ref` will be ready when it gets called.

So all you have to do is change your `onInit` like so:

```
̶$̶o̶n̶I̶n̶i̶t̶(̶)̶ ̶{̶
$postLink() {
    console.log("onInit", this.pl);
    this.initPL = this.pl || 'undefined';
    this.sample = this.pl || 'undefined';
    this.getSample = () => {
      this.sample = `[${this.pl.box1},${this.pl.box2}]`;
    }
}
```

> `$postLink()` - Called after this controller's element and its children have been linked. Similar to the post-link function this hook can be used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation. Note that child elements that contain templateUrl directives will not have been compiled and linked since they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been suspended until that occurs. This hook can be considered analogous to the `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngAfterContentInit` hooks in Angular. Since the compilation process is rather different in AngularJS there is no direct mapping and care should be taken when upgrading.
>
> Ref.: [Understanding Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

The full working snippet can be found bellow (I removed all `console.log` to make it clearer):

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", class ctrl {
  constructor() {
    //console.log("construct")
  }
  $postLink() {
    //console.log("onInit", this.pl);
    this.initPL = this.pl || 'undefined';
    this.sample = this.pl || 'undefined';
    this.getSample = () => {
      this.sample = `[${this.pl.box1},${this.pl.box2}]`;
    }
  }
})
.component("player", {
  template: `
    <fieldset>
      $ctrl.box1={{$ctrl.box1}}<br>
      $ctrl.box2={{$ctrl.box2}}<br>
    </fieldset>
  `,
  controller: class player {
    constructor() {
      //console.log("player",this);
    }
    $onInit() {
      //console.log("pl.init", this)
      this.box1 = true;
      this.box2 = false;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.7.1/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    Initial vm.pl = {{vm.initPL}}<br>
    Sample = {{vm.sample}}<br>
    <button ng-click="vm.getSample()">Get Sample</button>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.pl.box1" />
      Box1 pl.box1={{vm.pl.box1}}<br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.pl.box2" />
      Box2 pl.box2={{vm.pl.box2}}<br>
    <player ng-ref="vm.pl"></player>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent controller initialization happens before the initialization of the player controller, so that is why we have `initPL` as `undefined` in the first `$onInit`. 
Personally, I would prefer to define and load the data that should be passed down to the nested components on the parent controller initialization instead of setting the parent's initial data from its child's. But still if we will need this we can do it on the child's component initialization using bindings and callbacks. Probably it looks more like a dirty workaround, but it could work in such scenarios, here is the code:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", class ctrl {
  constructor() {
    console.log("construct")
  }
  $onInit() {
    console.log("onInit", this.pl);
    this.getSample = () => {
      this.sample = `[${this.pl.box1},${this.pl.box2}]`;
    }
    this.onPlayerInit = (pl) => {
      console.log("onPlayerInit", pl);
      this.initPL = pl || 'undefined';
      this.sample = `[${pl.box1},${pl.box2}]`;
    }
  }
})
.component("player", {
  bindings: {
      onInit: '&'
  },
  template: `
    <fieldset>
      $ctrl.box1={{$ctrl.box1}}<br>
      $ctrl.box2={{$ctrl.box2}}<br>
      <h3>Player</h3>
    </fieldset>
  `,
  controller: class player {
    constructor() {
      console.log("player",this);
    }
    $onInit() {
      console.log("pl.init", this)
      this.box1 = true;
      this.box2 = false;
      if (angular.isFunction( this.onInit() )) {
        this.onInit()(this);
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.7.1/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    Initial vm.pl = {{vm.initPL}}<br>
    Sample = {{vm.sample}}<br>
    <button ng-click="vm.getSample()">Get Sample</button>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.pl.box1" />
      Box1 pl.box1={{vm.pl.box1}}<br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.pl.box2" />
      Box2 pl.box2={{vm.pl.box2}}<br>
    <br>
    <player ng-ref="vm.pl" on-init="vm.onPlayerInit"></player>
</body>
```